# batch file that remembers what was copied

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

This was the initial question which I need to be "extended"
[Creating folder from file, copy initial file into folder and add prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150045/creating-folder-from-file-copy-initial-file-into-folder-and-add-prefix?answertab=active#tab-top)

This is the output batch

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (
    md "%%~nA"
    copy "%%~fA" "%%~nA\prefix_%%~nxA"
)
```

(if there is a .mp4, create a folder with that files name and copy the .mp4 into that folder)

Now that batch file should "remember" what folder was created so it wont restart the same operation every time when the newly created folder is deleted. 
I was thinking like "write the name into a .txt then perform rest from above bat" every new batch task could check if the name exists. if no = copy, if yes = do nothing.

Comment: You want to use the `IF NOT EXIST` command.

Comment: Your question is not clear. It may be _several_ .mp4 files? Suppose this: **1.** The file is "one.mp4", so it is copied to "one\one.mp4". **2.** The newly created folder "one" is deleted. **The question:** what to do if "one.mp4" file is processed again? Just don't copy it?

Comment: several mp4 files
if one.mp4 is processed again, it just ignore and dont copy.

Comment: @JanMüller I am not seeing the logic.  Why would the folder be deleted after it was processed and then why would you not want to process it again?

Comment: its a kind of backup for torrents. The torrent will seed but I can move or rename or whatever I want with the file. "delete" the folder was just to explain that the folder wont stay in that place forever  - maybe moved OR deleted...

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297899/3074564) written by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) is good and was voted up by me, but could result in wrong MP4 file processing under certain conditions.

The conditions on which wrong processing occurs are:

1. The *.mp4 files are stored on a FAT, FAT32 or exFAT instead of an NTFS drive.

   On FAT drives as often used on SD cards and USB sticks the file system returns files matching a pattern according to file allocation table entry (usually oldest first) and not sorted alphabetically according to name as NTFS file system always does.
2. There are MP4 files which names are substrings of other MP4 files with longer names.

   For example there is a file `Test1.mp4` which was created first on a FAT32 drive (first in file allocation table) and also a file `Test.mp4` which was created later and is therefore newer (second in file allocation table).

The usually working code written by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) results now with older `Test1.mp4` and newer `Test.mp4` on FAT32 drive in

- creating directory `Test1`,
- copying `Test1.mp4` into directory `Test1`,
- writing `Test1` into the text file,
- skipping processing for `Test.mp4` because string `Test` already found in text file as being a substring of `Test1`.

Following enhancements could be made to avoid this unwanted behavior under these conditions:

1. Use parameter `/ON` on command **DIR** to get the list sorted alphabetically by name as on NTFS drives.
2. Make sure not finding in text file the current file/directory name within a longer file/directory name.

And file/directory names are case insensitive on Windows which should be also taken into account on searching in text file using option `/I`.

The first solution uses also command **FIND** which does not have an option to match entire lines only. The file/directory name is written therefore with surrounding `:` into the text file and also searched with surrounding colons. A colon can't be in name of a file or directory making it a good start/end delimiter.

```
@echo off

if not exist FoldersCreated.txt cd . > FoldersCreated.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B /ON *.mp4') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I ":%%~nA:" FoldersCreated.txt >NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        md "%%~nA"
        copy "%%~fA" "%%~nA\prefix_%%~nxA"
        echo :%%~nA:>>FoldersCreated.txt
    )
)
```

Another solution is using **FINDSTR** with option `/X` to get a positive result only if searched string matches an entire line.

```
@echo off

if not exist FoldersCreated.txt cd . > FoldersCreated.txt

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /A-D /B /ON *.mp4') do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /M /X /C:"%%~nA" FoldersCreated.txt >NUL
    if errorlevel 1 (
        md "%%~nA"
        copy "%%~fA" "%%~nA\prefix_%%~nxA"
        echo %%~nA>>FoldersCreated.txt
    )
)
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `find /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`

**ATTENTION:**

Care must be taken on second solution on line `echo %%~nA>>FoldersCreated.txt` regarding trailing spaces. There should be no trailing space as otherwise **FINDSTR** never exits with 0 for an entire line match.

The code posted by [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) used as template for both solutions has 1 space at end of this line, i.e. there is **foldersCreated.txt**<kbd>space</kbd> on this line.

This trailing space is interpreted by command processor as being part of the text to output by command **echo** and therefore executed was by command processor:

```
echo Test1  1>>FoldersCreated.txt
echo Test  1>>FoldersCreated.txt
```

So the space at end of code line is moved after file name and is therefore written also into the text file. As there is no trailing space in search string on calling **FINDSTR**, there is never an entire line match.

It is no solution to use double quotes around file name, i.e.

```
echo %%~nA>>"FoldersCreated.txt"
```

Also with double quotes a trailing space is moved by command processor to end of text to output by command **echo**.

It is also no solution using

```
>>FoldersCreated.txt echo %%~nA
```

as a space at end of this line must be nevertheless avoided because command processor executes this line also as:

```
echo %%~nA 1>>FoldersCreated.txt
```

So any space after `%%~nA` would be nevertheless part of the text to output by **echo**.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

if not exist foldersCreated.txt cd . > foldersCreated.txt

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (
   find "%%~nA" foldersCreated.txt > NUL
   if errorlevel 1 (
      md "%%~nA"
      copy "%%~fA" "%%~nA\prefix_%%~nxA"
      echo %%~nA>> foldersCreated.txt 
   )
)
```

Comment: not working. the batch comes up empty...

Comment: @JanMüller - is the script in the same directory as your .mp4 files?

Comment: yes. the script is in the same folder.

Comment: You may remove the `@echo off` line and execute the Batch file from a command-prompt window: open cmd.exe, `cd` to the directory where the Batch file is and enter its name. The output in the screen will give you an idea of what the problem is.

Comment: "foldersCreated.txt" creates some kind of syntax error. As Im german, my OS gives a german error... :D

Comment: Ops, there is a small bug! In this part you must remove the "S": `if not existS ...`; it should be: `if not exist ...`. I already fixed the code above.