# Create a .txt file using BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to create a program that allows you to enter a username and password, then creates a folder with the same name as the inputted username, then creating a .txt file within the folder containing the password. For some reason my code for creating the .txt file doesn't seem to work. Instead of containing the password, the file is completely empty. Does anyone have the solution to my problem?

Here is my code:

```
    set /p newun=New Username: 
    set /p newpw=New Password: 

    if not exist C:\ProgramData\---\%newun% (
        mkdir C:\ProgramData\---\%newun%
        %newpw% > C:\ProgramData\---\%newun%\%newun%pw.txt
    ) else (
        echo %newun%'s directory already exists.
        pause
        goto start
    )
```

Comment: The script should have been throwing an error when it executed that line of code because the password would not be the name of a command it could execute.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add an `echo`. Your batch needs to look like:

```
(echo !newpw!)> C:\ProgramData\---\%newun%\%newun%pw.txt
```

In addition to this you need to put ...

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

... at the top of your batch.

This and the `(` / `)` around the echo and the variable holding the password are important because your password might contain characters that otherwise mess other things up (see comment by @dbenham). If someone puts a `>`, `<`, `&` and multiple other characters into his password this will otherwise break your script because if this becomes part of the batch its behaviour will change.

It's up to you to decide if you need to treat `newun` in a similar way.

Your current batch tries to call a program with the name of your password and takes the output of that program (which is none) and writes it to a file.

You can try this in order to see the effect:

```
doesnotexistforsure > output.txt
dir output.txt
```

Doing this you will get an "command not found" message and an empty file. Which is the same thing happening in your batch.

Comment: The space in front of  the redirection `>` will be written to the file. Might be problematic, when reading the Password back (I think that's what the file is intended to be used for). Better Syntax: `>Output.txt echo mypassword`

Comment: @Stephan You mean `echo %newpw%> output.txt` ? Because the other space does not matter and I think it is slightly more readable

Comment: @Marged - No, that is no good because it will fail if the last character in the password is a `1`. Then the one will be parsed as the stdout file handle and will be effectively stripped from the output.

Comment: @KoryGill - Of course your variable version doesn't generate a space at the end because you don't have a space in you source code before the redirect. But `echo %foobar% >foobar.txt` does generate the unwanted space. Your comment is a red herring.

Comment: @dbenham Have you tried ? At least on my Win10 this is no problem: `set pass=ThatsA2` / `echo %pass%> foo` / `type foo` will just return `ThatsA2`

Comment: @ThatsA2 - `echo %pass%> foo` will fail if `pass=ThatsA;1` (the 1 is stripped), same issue as my comment to Marged. `echo %pass% >foo` puts an unwanted space at the end. Two options that work are `>foo echo %pass%` and `(echo %path%) >foo`

Comment: `(echo %pass%) >foo` is very safe and even better would be `(echo !pass!) >foo` using delayed expansion in case of password contains a special character. All other variants are critical for various reasons including a by mistake added trailing space as described for example on my answer at [batch file that remembers what was copied](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34337759/3074564).

Comment: It's always very risky doing things with user inputs. In this case, if the user enters `one>two` as his password, it will mess things up. It's slightly safer to use _delayed expansion_.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch program reads what is **outputted** and stores it in a text document, so if you do `echo Hello` the **output** is `Hello` **not** `echo Hello` and if you type in `pause` the **output** is `Press any key to continue ...`, just like on the screen and not in the code.  If you type in `Password` for your `password` `%newpw%` will equal `Password` and if you do `echo: %newpw%` the screen will display `Password`, so the output is `Password`.  I would use `echo:` instead of `echo`, because `echo:` will allow the **output** to have spaces when it is saved in a text document and not have any errors like that Batch file just closing.

```
   echo: %newpw% >> C:\ProgramData\---\%newun%\%newun%pw.txt
```